# How to plot a scatter of coordinates

Tags: python, plot

I have the next lists:

pickup_nodes = [(42,29), (42,5),(69,134),(53,17)]

dropoff_nodes =[(54,176),(40,41),(0,37),(96,114)]

I want to draw a scatter of each list and differentiate between them with colors.........any help? each pair in each list represents (x,y)

Comment: Take a look at matplotlib and specially its scatter function : https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution using `matplotlib`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter([i[0] for i in pickup_nodes], [i[1] for i in pickup_nodes], c='red')
plt.scatter([i[0] for i in dropoff_nodes], [i[1] for i in dropoff_nodes], c='blue')
```